# Angular services breaks when combining

Tags: angularjs, service, npm

I have 2 services that I want to distribute with bower.
Categories (categories.service.js)
Product (product.service.js)

The both have the same structure like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('www', [])
    .service('Products', Service);

  Service.$inject = ['Restangular','$stateParams','$log'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function Service(Restangular, $stateParams, $log) {

    var service = {
      getProducts: getProducts,
      getProduct: getProduct
    };

    return service;

    function getProducts(numberOfProducts, $stateParams) {

      return Restangular.all('/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=' +
        numberOfProducts).customGET();
    }

    function getProduct(sku) {
      return Restangular.one('products/' + sku).customGET();
    }

  }
})();
```

Then I have my npm-script build

```
"build": "mkdir dist; npm run build:js & npm run build:min",
"build:js": "uglifyjs src/categories.service.js -b 'indent-level=2, quote_style=1' -o dist/service.js",
```

But for some reason only one of the services works when I add the services.js file.. ?

It works fine if I use them separately and not smashed into 1 file :)

Note: This is the output I get from the build

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('www', []).service('Categories', Service);
  Service.$inject = [ 'Restangular', '$log' ];
  function Service(Restangular, $log) {
    var service = {
      getCategories: getCategories,
      getCategory: getCategory
    };
    return service;
    function getCategories() {
      return Restangular.all('categories').customGET();
    }
    function getCategory(id) {
      return Restangular.one('category/' + id).customGET();
    }
  }
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('www', []).service('Products', Service);
  Service.$inject = [ 'Restangular', '$stateParams', '$log' ];
  function Service(Restangular, $stateParams, $log) {
    var service = {
      getProducts: getProducts,
      getProduct: getProduct
    };
    return service;
    function getProducts(numberOfProducts, $stateParams) {
      return Restangular.all('/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=' + numberOfProducts).customGET();
    }
    function getProduct(sku) {
      return Restangular.one('products/' + sku).customGET();
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: I suspect that redeclaring the `www` module overwrites the previous initialization (with the older Service).

Comment: Yes that seems to be the issue (just learned that it will override the module).. any ideas on a solution?

Comment: I guess I should use some namespace like 'www.products' and 'www.categories'.. but I would still like to only one module as a dependence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Style guide [says that:](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#setting-vs-getting)

> Only set once and get for all other instances.
>
> Why?: A module should only be created once, then retrieved from that
>   point and after.

So I would recommend declaring the module in a file separate from the services:

```
(function () {
  // Create module
  angular.module('my-www', []);
})();
```

And then to *get* it while declaring the services:

```
(function () {
  // Retrieve module
  angular.module('my-www').service(...);
})();
```

This should solve the issue.

---

As a sidenote, I would recommend create a more unique name for the module to avoid naming conflicts with other modules the application may want to use.

Comment: Spot on!.. Creating a 'app.js' that creates the module did the trick!.. thx!